# Add spacing before and after paragraph in iOS Pages?

Tags: pages, iwork

I don't see a way to edit this style property in the iOS version of Pages. (I'm using 4.0, March 2018). Am I missing it, or do I need to open the document on my macOS system to set this property?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of the current version (Pages iOS 4.0) it is not possible.

[Line height](https://help.apple.com/pages/ipad/4.0/) is supported but not spacing between paragraphs.

However, in addition to the macOS version, [iCloud Pages](https://help.apple.com/pages/icloud/#/gil56d107ce4) can do it too.

> Adjust the paragraph spacing:
>   You can control how much space appears before or after one or more paragraphs.
>
> Click to place the insertion point in the paragraph you want to adjust, or drag to select multiple paragraphs.
>
> In the Format sidebar on the right, below Spacing, click the up or down arrows, or enter a point value in the adjacent fields.

[image: iCloud Pages adjust paragraph tools]

[From the iOS documentation:](https://help.apple.com/pages/ipad/4.0/#/tan92235a2d6)

> You can adjust the margins for specific paragraphs to indent them from the document margins, and change the indentation of the first line of each paragraph.
>
> You can also increase or decrease the spacing between lines in a paragraph.

Comment: Seems like an important style. I submitted feedback to request it. I wonder if people have another way to put space around headers. I think the header styles look awful if they are sitting right on top of the body text, the way they do if you can't control the paragraph before/after spacing. Anyway, I'll accept answer.

Comment: Feedback is best.  Hopefully they will add it.  I can't imagine adding the feature to it would be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

From the Format sidebar, click the arrowhead next to Spacing. That will reveal the Before Paragraph and After Paragraph options. Then click the up or down arrows, or enter a point value in the adjacent boxes.

Comment: The OP is asking about iOS, do you have a screenshot?